# how to create Authcontroller in Auth folder in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Hai please i want one help from your side.i am working now  laravel 5.2 steam authentication.i am followed this below video link.All is well.but there is no inside of Auth folder in Authcontroller.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfHX-Hecu3k
```

my app.php has

```
 Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamServiceProvider::class,
```

how can i create another one authcontroller.php file in auth folder

Answer (score 0):

By default, Auth is not created when you install Laravel, you must run this command to scaffold all of the routes and views you need for authentication:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Please read the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs) thoroughly.

Comment: ya this comment is correct.Its make only Authcontroller  from in side of app\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php.but i want app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php

Comment: Then copy ```AuthController.php``` inside the ```Auth``` folder. Don't forget to change the namespace above. ```namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create `AuthController.php` with:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Then move this controller into the `Auth` directory. After doing that you'll also need to change controller's namespace and add namespace of the extended `Controller.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

You may also need to manually define auth routes instead of using `Route::auth()`